# SQL Having/Where clause to compare MAX from current/another table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, subquery, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I have a table that has date information and is being copied to another table and trying to perform an incremental load.
date = date format
hour = int

| person | date | hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| bill | 2023-01-02 | 2 |

```
select * into test.person_copy from 
(select * from original.person)
```

My thought process of performing the incremental load is to check on the max(date) & max(hour) from the original table against the copied table to identify what is the gap between the max values from both tables. However, I'm not entirely sure how to implement the logic as it doesn't seem straight forward with the where clause. Having clause might make more sense, but also doesn't seem correct?

```
select * into test.person_copy from 
    (select * from original.person org
         Having max(org.date, org.hour) > (select max(copy.date,copy.hour) from test.person_copy copy)
    )
```

The other variation I had in mind was to use HAVING NOT IN

```
Having max(org.date, org.hour) NOT IN (select max(copy.date,copy.hour) from test.person_copy copy)
```

Wasn't sure if logic is correct. Hour field will be of importance's, but can live with just the date fields.

Expected output would be that the logic would check for existing max(date) and only insert if it doesn't exist. Example below, 2023-01-03
| person | date       | hour |
|--------|------------|------|
| bob    | 2023-01-01 | 1    |
| bill   | 2023-01-02 | 2    |
| test   | 2023-01-03 | 2    |

Comment: Please edit your question and include an example of the **output** you would like from the data you have shown. If necessary, please include more examples so that we can understand the logic you are wanting to apply.

Comment: What should happen if the date is later, but the hour is earlier? (eg `2023-01-01 10am` vs `2023-01-02 6am`)

Comment: What is the datatype for `hour`? is it an integer or time or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have access to a RedShift environment but the following query should work:

```
select * 
into test.person_copy 
from original.person org
where dateadd(hrs, org.hour, org.date) > 
            (select max(dateadd(hrs, cpy.hour, cpy.date)) 
             from test.person_copy cpy
            )
```

This assumes that when the previous hour's copy was made entire set of source rows for that date&hour was copied (the new incremental load would have all rows for the dates&hours not already copied). This means that you need additional criteria in the select to make sure that you include only completed date-hours (i.e. make sure that you don't include the rows with hour=10 while the time is still 10:30).